# Keeping track of exceptions and whether or not they have been handled

Tags: python, error-handling, exception

> How would I keep track of exceptions so that I could find out whether
>   or not they have been handled or not?

Lets say I have some error handling code:

```
def errorWindow(self, error_):
    self.filewin = Toplevel(self.master)
    self.NothingLabel = Label(self.filewin,text=error_,justify=CENTER)
    self.NothingLabel.pack()
    self.nbutton = Button(self.filewin, text="OK", command=self.filewin.destroy)
    self.nbutton.pack(pady=5)

# When it is called it looks something like this:
    try:
       # Function that is being checked for exceptions
    except Exception as e:
        error_ = 'Failure the following error was encountered: \n {}'.format(e)
        self.errorWindow(error_)
```

What I want to do is use the function I have built to handle errors I expect will happen on the users end. I would like to have a function that also creates an error window for users when an error occurs that I do not expect. Ideally this should only happen if an exception has occurred. So is there a way to identify and track specific exceptions so that I may handle the unexpected errors in a different way than the ones that I do expect?

Comment: you should dig into the logging module of python

Comment: @PRMoureu Will do, thanks for the lead.